# Rspec expect keeps throwing a TypeError: nil is not a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

So I have this test in my app:

```
expect{
  post :create, :name=> 'abc'
}.to change(Event.count).from(0).to(1)
```

and it keeps throwing he this error:

```
TypeError: nil is not a symbol
```

Would anyone know why?

Comment: post your action `create` and full error output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the issue. Should be using {} instead of (). Should be this instead:

```
expect{
  post :create, :name=> 'abc'
}.to change{Event.count}.from(0).to(1)
```

Comment: For those not reading carefully, it's `{}` twice. So like here after expect and after change.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25227203/9595653

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it as below:

```
expect{
  post :create, :name=> 'abc'
}.to change(Event, :count).from(0).to(1)
```