# expected #count to have changed by 1, but was not given a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am testing my `model` method which returns me an `Account object`. I am checking whether my table has inserted a new `row` and my Model reflects its count.

Below is my spec.

```
 it "can create an account" do    
    create_account = Account.create(account: acc) 
    create_account.should change(Account, :count).by(1);
 end
```

Error i am getting

```
8) Account can create an account
     Failure/Error: create_account.should change(Account, :count).by(1);
       expected #count to have changed by 1, but was not given a block
```

Comment: BTW, this error happened to me because I was doing `expect(subject).to change ...` instead of `expect { subject }.to change ...`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `#change` matcher expects a block in which some action is performed that effects the expected change. Try this:

```
expect { Account.create(account: acc) }.to change{ Account.count }.by(1)
```

See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change

Comment: I am getting a NoMethodError: undefined method count for Account:Class

Comment: My Account model class is extending ActiveRestClient http://www.andyjeffries.co.uk/using-activerestclient-to-access-an-api/ is there anyway we can replicate count?

Comment: Sorry, don't know, but this is the correct way to use the `#change` matcher.

Comment: Thanks, i will ask another question with respect to ActiveRestClient.

Comment: Thilo, one help... https://github.com/whichdigital/active-rest-client i am using this... can you see anywhere there which can help me get the count?

Comment: Try `Account.all.size`?

Comment: expect { Account.create(account: acc) }.to change{ Account.count }.by(1) Here how can i use Account.all.size? Is it possible?

Comment: `expect { Account.create(account: acc) }.to change{ Account.all.size }.by(1)`

Comment: Expected result to have changed by (1) but was changed by 0

Comment: Ask a new question for this please.

Comment: `expect { Account.create(account: acc) }.to change(Account, :count).by(1)` - This also works & will avoid rubocop complaining about the coding style.

Answer (score 8):

Happens when you use `is_expected.to change { something }` instead of `expect { subject }.to change { something }`