# Testing model interactor - update attribute RAILS RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

how to write a Rspec test for update string attribute?
I have attribute: "status" and array for that = ['First','Second'] - model Post

`it "update status attribute" do
expect(@result).to change(Post, :status)
end`

is it correct?

My interactor:

```
class User::Post::RequestVerification <  ActiveInteraction::Base

  object :user

  string :status, default: nil
  integer :id, default: nil

  validate :status

  def execute
    update_status!
  end

  def post
    @post ||= post.find(id)
  end

  def update_status!
    @post.update_atrributes!(
        status: ['First', 'Second']
    )
  end

  def status
    errors.add(:base, 'error')
  end
end
```

My RspecTest:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe User::Post::RequestVerification do

  before do
    @result = User::Post::RequestVerification.run(new_params[:post])
  end

  let!(:user) {Post.new}
  let!(:user) { User.create }
  let!(:new_params) do
    {
        post: {

            status: 'First'

        }
    }
  end


  it "should update status" do
    expect(@result).to change(Post, :status)
  end

    end
```

I want to write a test to update one attribute.

Comment: Did you run it? what error or unexpected output do you see?

Comment: `expected #status to have changed, but was not given a block` 
and binding.pry
`@details={:base=>[{:error=>"error"}, {:error=>"error"}], :status=>[{:type=>"string", :error=>:invalid_type}]},
   @messages={:base=>["error", "error"], :status=>["is not a valid string"]}>`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the syntax of `change` is different. There is similar question with the similar error you mention. I won't copy the answer while I can refer you there.

[expected #count to have changed by 1, but was not given a block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227196/expected-count-to-have-changed-by-1-but-was-not-given-a-block)

Also, looks like you need to chain `change` with `by` or `from(..).to(..)`

Take a look at the documentation https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change

Comment: thanks, but this is correct way (using rspec matcher "to change") to write a test for update attribute?

Comment: Looks like its not the right way! Please take a look the documentation I posted in the answer. I updated it.

Comment: `expect { @result }.to change(@result, :status).from('First').to('Second')` what do you think about that?

Comment: Read the answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227196/expected-count-to-have-changed-by-1-but-was-not-given-a-block

Comment: but "to change" only belongs to numbers i.e from(1).to(2) ?? I don't need to increase count, but change a string value. It is possible using change to?

Comment: Yes. use `change{ @results.status }.from('First').to('Second')`